# Como poner un link en una imagen para que me lleven a una imagen

Tags: html, css

tengo un problema , hice un código donde hay un slider y aquí de vemos poner una imagen en cada presentación, ejecuta bien en el Bloc de notas  pero mi profesor dijo que tenemos que poner un enlace en una imagen para que nos envíe a una pagina creada en el Bloc de notas pero ya intente como hacerlo pero no sale quiero que algún programador me pueda ayudar, puedo pasa el código para que se puedan guiar.

Answer (score 1):

Estimado:

Dentro del código html de su slider debe buscar las imágenes que usted requiere que redireccionen a otra página, estas deben utilizar la etiqueta

```html
<img src="dirección imagen slider"/>
```

Una vez encuentre estas etiquetas, una alternativa puede ser la de encerrar la imagen con las etiquetas , dejándolas más o menos así:

```html
<a href="url para redirección"><img src="dirección imagen slider"/></a>
```

Asegúrese de que los css y las referencias en js apunten a la imagen del slider ahora que está dentro de la etiqueta del hipervínculo (etiqueta a).

Espero le sea de utilidad.